# How to imitate `twoside=semi` in ConTeXt?

Tags: header-footer, margins, context

ConTeXt's page setup seems to be very powerful for single pages. But as I am used to the powers of KOMA there is something I could not achieve: `twoside=semi`.

From what I have read I need to set up the page numbering to `alternative=doublesided` for being able to differentiate between odd and even pages. However, this will force the layout to flip sides (margins are adapted). Basically, I want to have the following layout (not to scale).

```
-----------------------  -----------------------
|                     |  |                     |
| -- ---------------  |  | --  --------------  |
| || |             |  |  | ||  |            |  |
| || |             |  |  | ||  |            |  |
| || |             |  |  | ||  |            |  |
| || |             |  |  | ||  |            |  |
| -- ---------------  |  | --  --------------  |
|                     |  |                     |
| ------------------  |  | ------------------  |
| | #                 |  |                # |  |
| ------------------  |  | ------------------  |
|                     |  |                     |
-----------------------  -----------------------
```

Code for a single-sided version:

```
\setuppagenumbering [alternative=singlesided,location={footer}]

\setuplayout        [grid=yes,
                     rightedge=1.25cm,
                     rightmargin=0pt,
                     rightmargindistance=0pt,
                     backspace=6cm,
                     leftmargin=4cm,
                     width=fit]
\showframe


\starttext
    Quack\margintext{Test}
    \page
    Quack\margintext{Test}
    \page
    Quack\margintext{Test}
\stoptext
```

So my question is: How to get double-sided page numbers while having a single-sided margin setup (margin with margin text on the left)?

What I have tried:

- messing around with footer setup and page number modulo 2 expressions
- layers (unfortunately their odd and even page detection only works for `alternative=doublesided`)
- using `alternative=doublesided` and `\definelayout[even][…]` to be the same as the `\setuplayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a document which has left and right pages but use the same layout for both of them use `location={singlesided,doublesided}` for `\setuppagenumbering`.

The location of the page numbers can be set with the `\setupfootertexts` command but you have add `location=` (or `location=none`) to `\setuppagenumbering` to disable the automatic placement of the number.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [location=,
   alternative={doublesided,singlesided}]

\setupfootertexts
  [] [pagenumber]
  [pagenumber] []

\starttext
\dorecurse{2}{\page[dummy]}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work for centered page numbers, but how may I achieve the effect depicted in the ASCII "art" in my question (page numbers that work like double-sided). Simply adding `margin` or `marginedge` turns out to keep the page number on one side throughout the document. Btw: Where are those options documented? I did not find them on https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuppagenumbering.