# ConTeXt sectioning alternative inmargin does not respect margins

Tags: sectioning, context

This is a follow-up to [How to imitate `twoside=semi` in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450849/124577). Basically, I want a single-sided layout with two-sided page numbering. That includes having a wide margin for marginal material only at one side (in this case left).

Unfortunately, the `\setuphead` alternative `inmargin` does not respect that there should only be one margin (neither does `margin`). Having set `rightmargin=0pt` you will see this behavior at subsection level:

[image: sub section in margin]

This happens on even pages. On odd pages, it does work as expected and the material is correctly placed:

[image: sub section in margin 2]

```
\setuppagenumbering [alternative={doublesided,singlesided}]
\setuplayout        [rightmargin=0pt,
                     backspace=8cm,
                     leftmargin=7cm,
                     width=fit]
\setuphead          [alternative=inmargin]
\showframe

\starttext
\startpart[title=PTest]
    \startchapter[title=CTest]
        \startsection[title=STest]
            \startsubsection[title=SubTest]
                Test
            \stopsubsection
            \page
            \startsubsection[title=SubTest]
                Test
            \stopsubsection
        \stopsection
    \stopchapter
\stoppart
\stoptext
```

*Question:* How can I replicate the behavior on odd pages on even pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have a double sided document ConTeXt switches the positions for the left and right margins for even pages. The `inmargin` alternative takes this into account when it places the number in the margin area but when you set `rightmargin` to `0pt` (which isn’t necessary because the margin areas don’t change the page layout) you set also the space between the left margin and the text block to `0pt`.

The first way to fix this is to set `rightmargin` to a value bigger than `0pt`.

```
\setuplayout
  [rightmargin=4cm,
   backspace=8cm,
   leftmargin=7cm,
   width=middle]
```

When you have newer version of ConTeXt you can also use a different method where you set a value to the `location` key for `\setuphead` which uses the `\margindata` command to place the number in the margin.

```
\setuphead
  [alternative=inmargin,
   location=inleft]
```

Comment: Thanks. The `location` key is great, but unfortunately only documented in `setup-en.pdf` and there one has to research the option names first…

Comment: The `location` key was added as a user request and it’s to this user to document it on the wiki. On other side in your case the distance is wrong because you set `rightmargin` to `0pt` for no real reason.

Comment: Ah, I see. Concerning the `rightmargin` setting the real reason is that I want to have something like `twoside=semi` produces and therefore only a `rightedge` is required, but no margin (there will be data in the margin, but only in the one margin that is intended, the left one). And if I change rightmargin to something larger than `0pt` it *does* influence the layout (try your settings vs mine in the OP).

Comment: The margins are controlled by the `backspaces`, `width` and `cutspace` values. The values for `leftmargin` and `rightmargin` do not change the visible margins on the paper and these two blocks can even extend outside of the visible area (which `leftmargin` does by default).

Comment: As I said, trying your settings instead of mine in the example in the OP I do get a very different layout. For me, after reading the post on layout (ConTeXtgarden wiki) the easiest layout construction has been to remove the right margin that I do not need and specify the left margin I will use and then use `width=fit`.

Comment: Use `width=middle` instead of `width=fit` because the `fit` option is meant to screen only documents, which also have edge areas for menus etc. which are taken into account to calculate the margins.

Comment: Ah yes, so I am able to reproduce my layout when specifying `cutspace` and `width=middle`.